# Hydraulic disc brakes operating by themselves

Tags: brakes, disc-brake

When cycling up steep inclines on my mtb sometimes the rear disc brake comes on without me being anywhere near the brake lever. I can tell it's doing it as it's gradual and pedalling becomes difficult.
It seemed to have been solved when the fluid was drained and refilled. After a couple of months it's started doing it again.
Any ideas?

Comment: Does the same happen in bike stand with bike angled? Maybe it's a case of rub due to lack of stiffness?

Comment: Does the brake release when you get off the incline? or does it stay stuck on?

Comment: Sounds like the brake is always rubbing slightly and overheating the fluid.  This may be combined with a setup that allows water to somehow get into the fluid reservoir.

Comment: @DanielRHicks But wouldn't that cause the brakes to gradually come on in all situations, rather than just when riding up hill?

Comment: Rim brakes or disk brakes? With rim brakes it could be lack of wheel stiffness or badly adjusted brakes.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: You are probably right, but especially in Austria and Germany hydraulic rim brakes are surprisingly common (considering their disadvantages). Probably Magura’s marketing influence …

Comment: @Michael Thanks -- I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus The brakes release when on the flat and sometimes if I tap the brake lever.

Comment: @Michael They are disc brakes.

Comment: @DavidRicherby The bike is a KTM Myroon
The bike shop mechanics are totally baffled by this.

Comment: Have you tried heating the calipers with sustained braking to see if the problem then occurs? Tried to replicate with the bike in a trainer?

Comment: What model brakes? Does the rotor/pad gap look good?